# prestashop back office combination price

Tags: prestashop

I am new to `prestashop` and I am very much disappointed by the back office entries in database. I have different products with more than 40,000 combinations generated by autogenerated combination. But every product has a different price and impact varies from product to product. I have issue with updating the prices, editing the prices I have to do all that nasty stuff manually or by one by one.

This work wasted lot of time to add the product entries and that giving them prices. Is there any way to edit, update only the price of the specific price after all possible combinations generated by `prestashop` itself.

Is there Any software or plugins available to make this work easier?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Prestashop doesn't handle specific price in combination. You ll have to calculate price increase.
We got the same issue each time we have to migrate data. 
I wouldn't recommend you to put a price at 0 on the main product price as it will appear at 0 on RSS and some modules.